# Is there a way to create a PowerShell script to stop the virtual machine automatically during the idle time of the virtual machine in azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

Please suggest me the powershell script to stop a virtual machine IN AZURE when it attains given maximum idle time and after that it must automatically starts running when the user logs into that virtual machine?

Comment: you can't log into a VM that is shut down...

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to create a scheduled task inside the VM.  That scheduled task will trigger when the machine is idle.  The script the task will run is:

`Stop-AzVM -Name <VM name> -ResourceGroupName <RG Name> -Force`

As for the second part of starting when a user logs on, that is not possible.  The VM will be off/de-allocated, there is nothing to log on to.

**NOTE:** the VM that has the scheduled task will also need the Azure Powershell modules installed on it and a [system managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-managed-identity-on-an-existing-vm).

[image: Create Task image]

Comment: Can you explain me in a detailed manner